# How would a legal system deal with random groundhog day events?

Tags: society, time-travel, law, law-enforcement, time-manipulation

I have seen similar questions about [groundhog day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film)) but they were about either a single unique groundhog day or a permanent one.

In this case, each day may or may not repeat. There are no limits so you could have one whole month without repeating followed by the same day repeating ten times. As in the standard groundhog, everyone remembers what happened but everything reverts to the way it was before at midnight.

That means that if the 3rd December is a looping day, at 23h59 you will suddenly be where you were at 0 AM. You will remember everything you did and so will everyone else, but the state of the world will be reverted back. If someone died they will be back, items that were created will disappear, computers will have the same data they held back then, etc.

Everyone remembers every single loop so if a day repeats three times, people will remember the three days of "false/erase" memories. The world has always been that way and it's common knowledge.

Suppose a world similar to our own but that has those random looping. I'm wondering how the legal system would deal with it. I have seen several problems that this would cause:

- If someone is arrested right away and there is a loop they realise they shouldn't have done this now and don't. The officers who arrested him could testify but that raises the issues of police framing people very easily and also the question of whether someone whose crime was erased should have the same punishment as someone whose crime stuck.
- If a looping happen during a trial, would they have to represent the same evidence they already did and hear the same witnesses again, would the jury have to redo their verdicts several times in a row if needed? Furthermore , knowing what happened the previous day would probably affect how the questions to the witnesses would go.
- There would probably also be huge issues with contracts.

For me this seems like a lose-lose situation. You either end up relying on memories and have to fully trust memory witnesses, have incomplete trial records and a hard time checking in the future (even 10 years later, who will remember all the details).

On the other hand, if you want to have records, you have to redo similar things again and again which might influence the results (bored juries, police wasting a lot of time trying to confirm if someone will "recidive", etc.).

What would be a "fair" system that allows appeal and suffer the minimum disruption from looping?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Akina! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: Hi Akina, I'm trying hard to figure out the internal logic of your world and it seems to me that the complexities are quite astounding. +1 . But I fear that it's too broad and opinion based. Which criterion will get the question closed first is a coin throw in this loop.

Comment: If people's memories are left intact, then what would stop someone from using a biological brain-esque form of data storage?

Comment: Hi Akina, do you mean a "Groundhog day for everyone" in a single shared universe, not personal multiverse?

Comment: Hi.
I mean a groundhog day for everyone,in a shared universe. Everyone is aware that the looping are happening, and when they happen, they happen to everyone at the same time. As for brain like computer to store data, I would assume they wouldn't be advanced enough for this to be a workable solution yet (though I assume that field would be way more active in that world than in ours).

Comment: @Akina, this is a interesting question, but unfortunately it is too broad (you are asking several questions at once). Thus, with a heavy heart I'm voting to close it.

Comment: I have seen several questions about law enforcement dealing with magic or other but I see groundhog questions tend to be too broad. Would restricting it to trials and ignoring everything else be sufficient or is this the core of the question just too broad to begin with ?

Comment: The problem with time-loop questions is that *anything* can happen anywhere in the world in any country under any legal system with any consequence.  That's always too broad. You would need to narrow this down to one specific action in one specific city on Earth (e.g., in Moscow today, if this specific occurance happened involving these specific people on iteration #3 of a 10-iteration loop, how might law change?) then maybe this could be reopened.  Otherwise, you're asking us to write your story for you and that's off-topic for the site.

Comment: I agree that this topic is too broad, but not for the reasons specified. There are too many open assumptions (some of which I addressed in my answer) that need to be filled in to make it less broad. Otherwise, there are just too many 'what if's' to give any answer. The criteria for a good answer are too hard to determine, given that a different assumption leads to a different criteria.You need to really, really tighten up the parameters as to what does and does not happen, hat is reset and what is not reset.

Comment: The big gaping hole in the original movie was, many times through he apparently has sex with a different prostitute or 'pick up'. When he comes out of the final iteration, will each one of these prostitutes recall that he had sex with them? What if they conceived? In THEIR iteration, their memory of the day would be what happened to them, and then they go on with their life. THEY do not iterate.Or DO they? Is the only thing that really happens, as far as the rest of the world is concerned, only what happened in the last iteration? That, for every other iteration, the timeline stopped?

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second in the original movie, there was no sign that anyone except Phil Connors (the main character) is iterating.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second I have tried making the concept clearer. Is it better ? (obviously for me I know what I means)

Comment: @Alexander But that means that, every time HE goes through a new iteration, another reality is formed for everyone that interacted with him. That is, every time he goes through a new iteration, whatever he did in that iteration would become permanent for everyone else but him. So do all of these 'realities' co-exist at the same time? If a woman became pregnant by having sex with him in one iteration, what happens? Does she stay pregnant when he reiterates and she continues her normal timeline? The movie is narcissistic - the only thing that matters is HIM.

Comment: Something that you might really want to look at is https://phys.org/news/2017-07-physicists-retrocausal-quantum-theory-future.htmlkim  9o

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second you are assuming that each iteration should somehow persist. What if it's just discarded?

Comment: @Alexander In which scenario, everyone goes back or Groundhog Day? If it is Groundhog Day, does it get discarded for everyone? In which case the curse is applied to everyone, they just don't remember it.

Answer (score 3):

This concept is intriguing.

I have a potential answer, but it depends on a lot of assumptions that are not clarified in the question, and they are too extensive to handle in the comments.

First, I am assuming that there is a philosophical difference between the mind and the body. That is, the mind exists independent of, but reliant upon, the existence of the body.

"Life', or the physical body part, is like a virtual reality game that the 'mind' part is playing, only every human is collectively part of the game. Just like a game, a 'save point' can be set, and the game continues, but if things do not go as expected, the player can reload the game as 'frozen' by the save point, and continue on. The player's mind, of course, remembers everything that happened the first time around, and can use that information to make modifications in her play so that this time around things will go differently. Except that, since it is a multi[player game, no one player can decide to go back to the save point. This option happens randomly, and beyond any player control.

Another difference is, the player's  mind and the body are intricately linked, so the mind has no other body, and the body has no other mind (the game avatar is, in fact, part and parcel of the  mind).

Another consideration is that the save point is always 24 hours (sort of like one 'turn'). You can not go back 48 hours, or 72 hours, or one week. Whatever happened up until 24 hours ago is unchangeable. It can not be redone. If you were falling off a cliff at the save point, you are falling at the same rate when the game is reset.

Another assumption - that the society has ALWAYS been this way, since 'creation', whatever form that takes.

Also, that everything physical gets reset - all of the laws of physics and all of the equations of physics, chemistry, and cosmology go back to exactly the same numbers, values, coordinates, states, that they were at reset. The physical body world is reset, but not the ephemeral mind part of the mind-body duality. The mind retains all of the experiences, memories, skills, wisdom. and knowledge gained.

**If my analogy and assumptions are correct, if this is your world, read on. If not, I suppose this answer can be deleted.**

In this scenario, a mistake that a person makes is not always final. If they mess up, there is a chance to re-play part of their life - one complete day's worth. But they can not depend on this. They can not plan on it happening. If they mess up, and the game gets reset to the last save, bonus for them. A second chance. If the game does not get reset, they are stuck with their decisions.

So if, for a crude example, one is married and decides to go on a hall pass, and has absolutely great mind-blowing sex with a stranger, but ends up with a communicable disease, if the day is reset they have the absolutely exquisite memory but not the consequences - they no longer have the disease. But they can not COUNT on the day being reset.

This happens even if something GOOD happens. That is, if they win a lottery and are set for life financially, and the day is reset, they can lose the lottery the next time around. Random chance is random, even between iterations.

**TL:DR**

The legal system by necessity would have to have as its basic tenet 'most recent most legal'. That is, the only thing that would be considered is the state of the world at the end of the latest iteration. Just like the end of a virtual reality game depends on the most current iteration, not on what happened in the iteration before the reset. You win or lose the game AT THE END, not in the middle. Some players that were winning, end up losing; some who were losing end up winning; but the only thing that matters is how the game ends.

There is no such thing as fair or unfair in life - things happen. Upsets happen. It gives, and it takes away. The only thing that really counts is how it is played out until the end, and the memories, skills, wisdom, knowledge, isight you gain along the way.

**EDIT**

Looked at from another angle, our legal system is based entirely on causality. We did something that caused something else to happen. Everything is sequential.

Consider the following argument in a court of law:

"You woke up this morning and you visited your ex-spouse, you got in an argument with her, and you killed her. You had great remorse for what you did. So when you got up this morning, you remembered the consequences of you going to see your ex-wife later in the day, and you decided not to visit her. So you did not kill her. So when you woke up this morning, the consequences of your actions later on in the day caused you to do something different in the past, so your wife is not dead."

Where is the chain of causality? The act of killing her lead to you not doing something that lead to you not killing her.

The only arguably legally pertinent 'causality' chain is the most recent one. You  did not kill her, therefore you are not responsible for nor did you cause her death.

Comment: In the end, considering the final state when a looping day end and ignoring everything that was erased does seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Otherwise you are looking at contradictions in causality. If I do something during the day that goes badly, the day 'loops' back the  the beginning and I start all over, and because of my 'memories' of what happened IN THE FUTURE, and I change my tactics, has the future CAUSED my actions IN THE PAST (the beginning of the new iteration)? Can causality go in the reverse direction? Can the future cause the past? https://phys.org/news/2017-07-physicists-retrocausal-quantum-theory-future.html

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that in most depictions of a Groundhog Day loop (including the one in the eponymous film), only one or a small group of people can remember what happened.  You seem to be assuming that everyone in the loop remembers, so I'll answer under that assumption (your world; your rules).

Starting with the last:

#### Contracts

If a contract has physical requirements, including money, then the person has to make sure they are in compliance after the groundhog loop ends.  Requiring compliance within the loop seems problematic, as it seems likely that people will get tired of repeating the same actions for no result.

The most natural thing might be to make groundhog days into business holidays.  Because until the last day, the actions don't really count.  Most contracts would explicitly handle issues like loops, because they would be expected.  It would be natural to push out the deadline if a loop holiday prevented the delivery date.

The only event within the loop that would be controlled by contract would be those enforcing secrecy.  A loop would not obviate the need to keep information private.  Because information transfers are the only thing that can persist past the loop.

#### Trials

The first day, they would have to hold the trial.  Because they don't know that they'll loop (at least as I understand your rules).  But I suspect that they would call it off for the remaining days of the loop.  Because they wouldn't be able to keep any of the physical records from the day.

I suspect that you are correct that they would have to redo that first day.  Yes, it may disrupt the trial.  To reduce the impact of that, trials may concentrate more on affidavits and less on direct testimony.  The reason being that it is easier to redo an affidavit than a cross examination.

#### Erased crimes

It would make sense for property crimes to only count on the last day, when they actually take effect.  Because that's the only day when someone actually loses the property.  But violent crimes should be illegal whenever.  Because the trauma from, for example, rape, is more mental than physical.

They may get prosecuted less, as it might be harder to gather evidence.  But such crimes should stay criminal.  And it's not like there aren't crimes prosecuted purely on witness testimony now.  Such prosecutions are possible albeit more difficult.

Comment: Most of this assumes they KNOW they are going to loop again, and that they KNOW when and what the 'last loop' is going to be.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I read it as everything is repeated on the day *after* the loop ends. So for a trail, it's held as normal. Then they discover it's a loop, so it's auto-postponed. Once the loop ends (Which is fairly obvious with any sort of mechanical or electronic datekeeping), it's time to go back to trial.

Comment: @Andon  Okay, I get it, First loop counts, all others are ignored. Interesting take. But what happens if you die in the third loop?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond  Your world.  Your rules.  What does happen if you die in the third loop?  Wouldn't you just come back to life in the next loop?  That was my assumption when writing the answer.  And yes, I'm assuming that you know when the loop is over even though you don't know when the loop starts.  I.e. the first iteration of the loop looks like a normal day.  Subsequent iterations are easily recognizable.  It would be on the news.  "Hey folks, astronomers tell us that we're in another loop.  So just take the day off.  We're going to put the station on automatic and go home."

Comment: @Brythan Okay, it makes sense, except that if the third loop were the last loop, and you did NOT go back to the beginning of the  day again, wouldn't you stay dead? i had sort of assumed hat it was the LAST iteration of the day that counted, not the first. And that randomness was random between iterations.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond  Sure, if it's the last loop.  But not any other iteration (including the first).  I'm saying that people would have to live the first loop as if it counted (because they don't know it's a loop).  After that, they'd just take a holiday.  This would give them a holiday that counted on the last day, but that seems a reasonable allowance after say ten that don't count.

Comment: Methinks we need the OP to come in and give us some advice as to whether we are on the right track or not.

Comment: But I do agree that, even though psychology was not in the scope of this question, it would be germaine to know a bit about the mindset of people who have always known that any particular day might or might not be  definitive to their future.

Comment: Can you imagine the "pain & suffering" lawsuits that would derive from crimes occurring in previous iterations since all are remembered?  Of course, the real problem is the need to rely on witnesses from previous iterations since there would be no video tape - no way to permanently record proof of the crime.

Comment: @JBH For sure, psychological/psychiatric services would be impacted, especially things like PTSD, but it begs the question be asked, 'when the world is reet each iteration, is trauma remembered or reset? That is, is trauma separate from memory of the event?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, the OP has made it clear that everyone remembers every iteration.  Memory = trauma (at least you can bet that would be the interpretation of ambulance-chasing lawyers).

Comment: @JBH On this point, the OP would have to clarify, probably in another question as brain physiology seems to be outside the scope of this one.  In the human, trauma is stored in a different region, and in a different fashion, than memories. Trauma is stored in part as a chemical memory, subject to drug intervention, so it might be reset when everything physical resets, just like a wound might reset. If it were always like this with them, then ambulance chasers would have no experience with it. But that is certainly another question.

Comment: I was assuming trauma would be included within memories but I'm not a brain expert. Could you remember something that happen to you without feeling affected by it ?
That's an interesting take on it with making a "looped" day one a "holiday" and just waiting until it ends and ignore it

Comment: Re-thinking this, it would seem to me that the 'memories' from past iterations would be like dreams. It would be as if they were remembering something that really didn't happen, because there is no physical evidence of it happening. So at the beginning of every new iteration day, it would be like they were awakening from a dream that 'foretold' the future.

Comment: What actual PROOF would they have that the previous iteration actually happened? Thee is no physical evidence, just their 'memories', like the memories we have about the dream we just had.

Comment: There is a really nice theory, but I can not find my reference to it, that time goes backwards AND forwards, we just do not know it because we can not REMEMBER the future until it happens. So if time went backwards, how would we KNOW it? Our memories would ALSO go back in time.